# Running rails app with kompose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, devops, kompose

I've created `docker-compose` file for my app and encountered a problem with running it with `kompose`. I know that problem is in volumes, but I don't know how to fix it.

**docker-compose**

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    entrypoint: [bin/entry.sh]
    image: myimage:latest
    command: rails server -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links: 
      - postgres
  postgres: 
    image: postgres:9.4
    ports:
      - "5432"
```

When I run kompose up, everything looks ok, but the container with app keeps crashing, because it can't find files form app directory.

Is it possible to build a container which contains these files and use it with Kompose?